# AngularJS $http is undefined after page refresh

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am injecting $http to my service like that:

```
lightconsole.service({
ibus : function($http) {        
    var location = angular.element("#location").val();
    return new IBus($http, location);
},
storage : function() {
    return new Storage();
},
funlist : function() {
    return new FunctionList();
}
});
```

Everything work well, until page refresh. Then $http is undefined, why?

Comment: Page refresh means reload of whole application. That usually means there's some logic in your application that's wrong. The code above is not enough to diagnose that.

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv this is all logic behind it :) I only got one more line where lightconsole is declarded: `var lightconsole = angular
  .module('lightconsole', [ "ui.router", "datatables" ]);`

Comment: So AngularJS is creating instances of your `ibus` service and passing it the `$http` dependency. That should happen all the time and I'd be very surprised it what happens to you is a bug in AngularJS itself and not your code. That's why I'm asking what else are you doing, because this piece of code should always work.